# Convert Hex Number from Solidity

Tags: solidity, javascript

```
var contract = await tronWeb.contract().at(contractAddress);
var result = await contract.getPlayerDeposit("").call();
```

Output:
I got in array:
(4) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
0: Array(1)
0: v {_hex: "0x00", _ethersType: "BigNumber"}
length: 1
**proto**: Array(0)
1: Array(1)
0: v
_hex: "0x5f887761"
_ethersType: "BigNumber"
**proto**: Object
length: 1
**proto**: Array(0)
2: [v]
3: [v]
length: 4
**proto**: Array(0)

How to convert hex number? I'm using javascript to retrieve data from contract?

Best
Chris

Comment: What is `getPlayerDeposit` return type? Javascript doesn't natively support numbers required by ethereum so it will use a wrapper like BN.js or Bignumber.js. You can convert them to decimal string representation with `toString()` or to an hexadecimal string with `toString(16)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to convert the `BigNumber` into a normal number, you can do that by:

```
result[0].toNumber()
```

But keep in mind that JavaScript's [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) is a 64 bit number, so the `uint256` in your solidity contract might not always be shrinked down to 64 bits.

A safer way to to that is to keep the number in String, if you don't want to do any additions or substractions on it.

```
result[0].toString()
```

If the number is not going to be very big, you can keep it `uint32` in your contract, that automatically makes the ethers.js to convert it into a JavsScript Number by default.